# Catch JSON response using ModSecurity

Tags: mod-security

I'm using ModSecurity to catch a string from JSON response and log it.

Here is a sample HTTP Request and Response:

Request:

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Pragma:no-cache
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
{"data":{"username":"andrew","password":"AndreWTestingUser123dddd","remember":false,"authType":0}}
```

Response:

```
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 02 Feb 2015 10:39:15 GMT
Server:Apache
{"status":401,"messages":["Invalid password. (error code: 401)"],"createCookie":false}
```

This the rule i wrote:

```
SecRule STREAM_OUTPUT_BODY "@rx (?i)Invalid password"\
        "id:9900022, \
        phase:4 \
        log, \
        pass, \
        chain, \
        t:none, \
        msg:'Invalid VT login detected', \
        logdata:%{RESPONSE_BODY}"
SecRule RESPONSE_HEADERS:Content-Type "application/json" \
        "log, chain"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/api.php/auth/login" \
        "log"
```

However ModSecurity is not loggin this request as expected.

Here is my ModSecurity Version Info:

```
ModSecurity for Apache/2.8.0 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
APR compiled version="1.3.9"; loaded version="1.3.9"
PCRE compiled version="7.8 "; loaded version="7.8 2008-09-05"
LIBXML compiled version="2.7.6"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JSON inspection is not compiled into modsecurity by default. You need to re-compile your modsecurity installation with libyajl JSON library to enable JSON support

this link shows how to do this
https://gist.github.com/rpfilomeno/1140359f4bd360137a98

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled SecStreamOutBodyInspection directive? And I presume it needs SecResponseBodyAccess enabled too.

Both are disabled by default so you can't inspect response body details. Be warned there can be quite a performance hit for scanning output (which is why it's off by default).